# How to get Single Value From Database through Entity Framework

Tags: mysql, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a table that represent userInfo. My requirement is get last value of table as userID. Table structure is

```
-------------------------------------
userID  |  username  |  password  
-------------------------------------
```

I use MYsql as database and userID is auto-increment.

I try this code but it not working in my controller

```
var userID = db.users.Max().userID;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
var userID = db.users.OrderByDescending(u => u.userID).Select(u => u.userID).FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 0):

Your request should be :

```
var userId = db.Users.Max(u => u.userID);
```