# Return one value from query C#, EF Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, iqueryable

So here is my method that gets Course for the specific groupId. The thing I want to do is to get only CourseId from the database table. This method now returns List. How can I get ONLY CourseId value from the table, not the list?

```
public async Task<List<PupilGroup>> CheckDoesTeacherCanSeeGroupAsync(long teacherId, long? groupId)
    {
        var courseOfGroup = await _applicationContext.PupilGroups
                 .Where(x => x.Id == groupId)
                 .Select(x => new PupilGroup
                 {
                     CourseId = x.CourseId
                 })
                 .ToListAsync();
        return courseOfGroup;
    }
```

Please direct me

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get Single Value From Database through Entity Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26559330/how-to-get-single-value-from-database-through-entity-framework)

Comment: "gives 'long' does not contain a definition for 'GetAwaiter'... Couldn't find in Google the reason for that" - then i suggest LEARNING C#. The concept behind async/await is not exactly NOT in the documentation, as async is a core concept of the language. If you miss that, you likely miss a LOT of basics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By not making it a ToListAsync() and by not making int a PupilGroup.

```
.Select (x => x.CourseId).FirstOrDefault();
```

instead of projecting it into an object and then turning it into a list. Note that FirstOrDefault may also be a sum, min, whatever - depending on whether you actually HAVE only one item there.

Comment: Thank you so much! I also wanted to ask: I tried to do like you recommended, and it worked only when I removed Async things and left public long... (it gave me 'long' does not contain a definition for 'GetAwaiter'...), I don't clearly understand, why it gives an error like that?

Comment: @Sam you need to do `await ......Select (x => x.CourseId).FirstOrDefaultAsync();` then

Comment: @MatthiasBurger thank you so much for your response. I know, I did it like that (I edited my question). Still gives me this..

Comment: @Sam .. yeah simply change `FirstOrDefault()` to `FirstOrDefaultAsync()` because you can't await an int64 :D

Answer (score 1):

If I understood correctly your intention - try this:

```
var courseOfGroup = await _applicationContext.PupilGroups
                 .FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == groupId)?.CourseId;
```

Comment: this is correct, no question. but the better solution is to `Select(x=>x.CourseId)` first and do then `FirstOrDefault()`  because otherwise, you would fetch a complete row from DB, when you only need `CourseId`. (You never know what's in that row - large `byte[]`-file or something?) - and for retrieving a single-value, because you fetch on primary-key `SingleOrDefault()` would be better/clearer.

Comment: @Matthias Burger you are absolutely right, cheers for heads up.

Answer (score -3):

```
.FirstOrDefault(x => x.CourseId)
```

Use the FirstorDefault() method to return the first element of a sequence or a default value if element isn't there. List val = new List { }; Now, we cannot display the first element, since it is an empty collection. For that, use the FirstorDefault() method to display the default value

Comment: This is incorrect. The parameter for the `.FirstOrDefault(...)` method is the criteria that is verified when finding the first row that applies, it is **not** the projection that is made on that first record.